# Probability of alternating heads/tails - infinite coin tosses

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-explanation

> We toss a fair coin until we get two consecutive heads or two consecutive tails. Each sequence of $n$ coin tosses has a probability of $\frac{1}{2^n}$.
>
> What is the probability that this experiment never stops?

In my homework I suggested:

If the experiment doesn't stop the resulting sequence must attain one of the two forms
\begin{align*}
&\omega=(\text{Kopf, Zahl, Kopf, Zahl, }\dots) \text{ or}\\ 
&\omega'=(\text{Zahl, Kopf, Zahl, Kopf, }\dots).
\end{align*}
Hence,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}\cup\{\omega'\})=2\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=0,
\end{align*}
as $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is a null sequence.

---

My tutor wrote that this is wrong because the way I described it doesn't guarantee that the event is impossible. Further, he added that I had to assume an uncountable sample space to make my argument work.

Can someone explain to me what he means and why my approach is wrong?

Comment: First, the sample space is still countable.  It can be thought of as $\{s~\mid~s~\text{is a finite sequence ending in two consecutive heads or two consecutive tails}\} \cup \{\omega,\omega'\}$ where $\omega$ and $\omega'$ are defined as above.  It should be clear that the set above is a countable set unioned with a finite set and thus countable.  Second, it should be emphasized the difference between "*improbable*" and "*impossible*".  The event is indeed improbable, also called "*almost impossible*" or that it happens "*[almost never](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)*"

Comment: @JMoravitz I should have rather written "impossible". See my edit.

Comment: Now... whether you formally treat the sample space as above with the unioned $\{\omega,\omega'\}$ or if you treat it as though those two were not unioned in and they were missing... in either treatment the probability that you encounter either is zero, either because it truly is impossible or because it merely happens almost never.  Both are valid.

Comment: @JMoravitz but why does "merely happens almost never" mean that the probability is $0$?

Comment: "*event $A$ happens almost never*" is just the fancy way of saying that the probability of $A$ is zero.

Comment: The reason why it is probability zero here?  For exactly the reason you stated in your post.  The probability of forever alternating heads and tails, that would mean that our sequence began with a finite string of alternating heads and tails of length $n$.  Recalling that if $A\subseteq B$ then $\Pr(A)\leq \Pr(B)$, letting $B_n$ be the event we began with $n$ alternating heads and tails we have $B_1\supseteq B_2\supseteq B_3\supseteq \cdots \supseteq A$ and so $\Pr(B_1)\geq \Pr(B_2)\geq \cdots \geq \Pr(A)$, the probability of $\Pr(B_n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$ implying $\Pr(A)=0$

Comment: @JMoravitz hmm then I still don't understand what my tutor means. It was like that she really wanted to emphasize that we can't do it this way by writing the probability of a set as a limit...

Comment: I suggest discussing the matter with your tutor.  She may want to emphasize the fact that the "event" in question is ill defined, as you can not actually throw the coin infinitely often. I would be surprised to learn that she has some definition of the infinite event other than as a limit of finite events, but you should ask.